Large Deviation Principle for an adaptive sampling rule for Multi Armed Bandits
Consider the following adaptive strategy for sampling from a Multi Armed Bandit with $K$ arms:

Split the $T$ rounds into $N (\in \mathbb{N})$ disjoint intervals. Each interval is indexed by $i=1,2,\dots,N$. We assume $N$ is fixed and $T>>N$.
For each interval $i$, we have an allocation function $w_i: ((w_1,\bar{X}_1),(w_2,\bar{X}_2),\dots,(w_{i-1},\bar{X}_{i-1})) \to \Delta_K$, i.e, a map from the history of allocations and sample averages it decides to sample the arm $a$ in the $i^{th}$ interval according to the proportions $w_i(a)$. Here $\bar{X}_i$ denotes the $K$-dimensional vector containing the $K$ sample means (one for each arm) from the $i^{th}$ disjoint interval.

Question 1: Does the $N$-tuple $(\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2,\dots, \bar{X}_N)$ satisfy a LDP as $T \to \infty$? If indeed it does, it would be great to get a closed form dependence on allocation functions $w_i$ in the rate function. Any sort of (reasonable) regularity assumption on arm distribution might added to derive the result.
For $N=1$ it is known to be true regardless of the nature of the allocation function $w_1$. See for example Glynn-Juneja 04 for a simple argument based on Gartner Ellis. Based on their work, intuitively for $N\geq 2$ it feels like the rate function should have the form :
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N}_{i=1}\sum^{K}_{a=1}w_i(u_1,\dots,u_{i-1})(a)I_a(u_{i,a})
$$
where $I_a(.)$ is rate function associated with an individual arm, and the large deviation exponent for a set $A$ has the form:
$$
\underset{(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_N) \in A}{inf} \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N}_{i=1}\sum^{K}_{a=1}w_i(u_1,\dots,u_{i-1})(a)I_a(u_{i,a}).
$$
This form has an intuitive appeal-  we take the deviations of each arm in a disjoint interval $i$ and then sum them across arms and intervals in an appropriate weighted manner.
For $N=2$, I feel one can again use Gartner Ellis in the following nested manner:
Consider the mgf for $(\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2)$:
\begin{aligned}
e^{\Lambda_T(T\lambda)}&=E[e^{\langle T \lambda,(\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2)\rangle}]\\
&=\int e^{\langle T \lambda_1,u_1\rangle}E[e^{\langle T \lambda_2,\bar{X}_2\rangle}|\bar{X}_1=u_1]\mathbb{P}_T(\bar{X}_1 \in du_1)\\
&=\int e^{\langle T \lambda_1,u_1\rangle}e^{T/2\cdot(\sum_a w_2(u_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(u_1)(a))}\mathbb{P}_T(\bar{X}_1 \in du_1)\\
&=\int e^{T(\langle \lambda_1,u_1\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(u_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(u_1)(a))}\mathbb{P}_T(\bar{X}_1 \in du_1)
\end{aligned}
where $\Lambda$'s are the appropriate cumulant functions for various distributions. Now from the result of $N=1$ we note that the family of measures $(\mathbb{P}_T(\bar{X}_1 \in \cdot))_{T \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies an LDP with rate function:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(.)
$$
and hence one can invoke Varadhan's lemma to evaluate the limit:
\begin{aligned}
\underset{T \to \infty}{lim}\frac{\Lambda_T(T\lambda)}{T}&=\underset{T \to \infty}{lim}\frac{\log\big( \int e^{T(\langle \lambda_1,u_1\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(u_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(u_1)(a))}\mathbb{P}_T(\bar{X}_1 \in du_1)\big)}{T}\\
&=\underset{u_1}{sup}(\langle \lambda_1,u_1\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(u_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(u_1)(a))-\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(u_{1,a})
\end{aligned}
Thus the usual Gartner Ellis limit will exist and $(\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2)$ will satisfy a LDP with rate function which is the fenchel conjugate of the above limit.
Question 2: Is the above obtained rate function just a disguised version of the heuristic guess we have for $N=2$? I haven't been able to relate the two rate functions.
Edit: Let us denote:
$$
\Lambda(\lambda)=\underset{T \to \infty}{lim}\frac{\Lambda_T(T\lambda)}{T}=\underset{u_1}{sup}(\langle \lambda_1,u_1\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(u_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(u_1)(a))-\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(u_{1,a}))
$$
The fenchel conjugate of this limiting cumulant function then is:
$$
\Lambda^{*}(v_1,v_2)=\underset{\lambda}{sup}(\langle \lambda_1,v_1 \rangle+\langle \lambda_2,v_2 \rangle-\Lambda(\lambda))
$$
But from the variational form of $\Lambda(\lambda)$ we have:
$$
\Lambda(\lambda) \geq \langle \lambda_1,v_1\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(v_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(v_1)(a))-\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(v_{1,a})
$$
Hence we have that:
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda^{*}(v_1,v_2) &\leq \underset{\lambda}{sup}(\langle \lambda_2,v_2 \rangle-\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(v_1)(a)\Lambda_a(2\lambda_{2,a}/w_2(v_1)(a))+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(v_{1,a}))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_1(a)I_a(v_{1,a}))+\frac{1}{2}\sum_a w_2(v_1)(a)I_a(v_{2,a}))
\end{aligned}
Hence the Question 2 is false.

I guess on further thought it seems clear that the LDP rate function derived is always upper bounded by the heuristic guess. Hence the heuristic rate function is not the right rate function and the answer to question 2 is false.
